# How long does it take to upgrade Magento from 2.0.2 to 2.0.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0

I started magento 2 upgrade over a half hour ago.

The on screen console log shows:

```
[2016-04-26 20:45:03 EDT] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has been started
[2016-04-26 20:45:03 EDT] Magento maintenance mode is enabled.
[2016-04-26 20:45:03 EDT] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has successfully completed
[2016-04-26 20:45:04 EDT] Job "update {"components":[{"name":"magento/product-community-edition","version":"2.0.3"}]}" has been started
[2016-04-26 20:45:04 EDT] Starting composer update...
[2016-04-26 20:45:04 EDT] ./composer.json has been updated
```

It seems to be hung.

Is it working? How long does it take?

Comment: It seems my system is no longer working.

How do I get back to v 2.0.2?

Comment: you can upgrade from admin as well as using cli . http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/compman-start.html .

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade your magento 2 using terminal. 
With another words, go to magento website, download latest version of magento 2. 
Upload it to your server. After that exctract it to your root magento folder. 
That's it. Let me know if you need another help.

Comment: And it continues to run with the current database intact? No impact to DB or loss of products, sales, orders, customers, etc. @LedianHymetllari ?

Comment: because my site has been down for 12 hours now. Error 503 Service Unavailable -- Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: Yes it will run with current database. It will save your orders , customers ando other things that are saved to database. Just back up first your magento files and db, then upgrade it

Comment: I fixed it via googleing. (For Magento 2) simply delete /{magento site's doc root}/var/.maintenance.flag and the site comes back online

Comment: I'm going to stick with v2.0.2 -- Magento is way too complex of a system to mess with updates & upgrades.

Comment: There is another file you have to delete to get upgrade to start over. It's also in `var` and its name is `.upgrade.status` or something

Comment: FWIW, [how to upgrade Magento using the command line](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Comment: Great, now products will not appear on the public web site. I can add them in the backend admin ui panel but they do not appear on the site. I flush and flush and flush and nothing. Any advice @LedianHymetllari?

Comment: any help or advice @SteveJohnson?

Comment: Did you added iventory, or enabled products?

Comment: yes and Yes. Product is Online and In Stock with a Qty of 1 @LedianHymetllari