# How to Retain Double Quotation Marks on Product Attributes

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, magento-2.0, quote

When we enter product attributes in the Admin ad Storeview boxes, double quotation marks `"` get transformed into their HTML ASCII code equivalent `&quot;`.

How can we retain double quotes? (It is used to represent the American Inch Symbol for sizes.)

Here's a **before** the update screen shot:
[image]

Here's an **after** the update screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Is `&quot;` present in DB or when you print the value? It's actually better to have it rendered as `&quot;` on frontend, than `"`.

Comment: I can check @nevvermind...which table would that be in (here are dozens of product related tables in there)? I can tell you that regardless, `&quot;` is what appears on the public web site which means the html ascii code does not parse. And, as for the table, I would bet that it is in the DB table as `&quot;` otherwise where else would it be stored that way?

Comment: I still think that, in DB, the actual `"` char is stored, and _escaped_ on [output](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/f10c7c83a93628122a929949b97e08faa13ce652/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Escaper.php#L20). Can you post a pic, though? I think we're talking different things here. Dunno what `the Admin ad Storeview boxes` are, so I assumed an attribute value.

Comment: Right, that's a bug. "Lobby" for it here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4351. You should add there the pic links above.

Answer (score 1):

This is already fixed in develop branch and will be released as part of 2.1, possibly earlier with a patch release as well.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad @PiotrKaminski because once you install Magento 2.0.2 you're stuck wit it. It is not upgradable. See my 4 related posts: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112800/how-long-does-it-take-to-upgrade-magento-from-2-0-2-to-2-0-3, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114275/how-long-to-wait-for-a-magento-2-x-upgrade, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114292/how-to-tell-if-system-upgrade-is-still-running-via-web-interface, and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/how-to-update-magento-2-0-2-to-v-2-0-3.